# How to Use Xamarin.Forms With Xamarin.Android and Xamarin.IOS?

Tags: android, ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

Hello Every one we have an Application that is built on Xamarin.IOS(IOS App) and Xamarin.Android(Android App) and a shared Project that contains shared Resources which is Used by both projects

Now if Both projects there are some screen that can be easily build on Xamarin.Forms, so it is possible to use Xamarin.Forms with xamarin.Android and Xamarin.IOS project

or

is there any way to Convert a Xamarin.Android and Xamarin.IOS screen to Xamarin.Forms

Any links,suggestions or any way to achieve this without changing current projects structures

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible to call Xamarin.Forms pages from Xamarin.Android and Xamarin.iOS projects, in Xamarin this is call Native2Forms.

You will use the Xamarin.Forms App class as your connection between your two projects.

This is a sample project from Xamarin showing how you can do that.
https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/master/Native2Forms

Regarding the converter, No, I don't think there's a way of converting Android XMLs and/or iOS Storyboards/XIBs into Xamarin.Forms Pages (XAML).